# Copy Directory not working

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to copy a directory into another directory using the following code but for some reason, it is only copying the contents of the directory and not the directory itself.

```
        Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(TextBox1.Text, My.Settings.FSXLocation & "\SimObjects\Airplanes", True)
        MsgBox("Your 737-800 Aircraft has now been Installed.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Figerty Systems Inc")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Figerty Systems Inc.")
    End Try
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Edit** - more code:

```
        Try
        Dim arg = String.Format("{0} {1} /i/y/s/e/D", Path.GetFullPath(TextBox1.Text), Path.GetFullPath(My.Settings.FSXLocation & "\SimObjects\Airplanes"))
        Dim p = New Process()
p.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo() With { _
    Key .FileName = "xcopy", _
    Key .Arguments = arg, _
    Key .UseShellExecute = False, _
    Key .RedirectStandardOutput = True _
}
        p.Start()
        Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
        p.WaitForExit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("[FAIL] COPY: {0}", ex.Message)
        Throw
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows API doesn't support copy directory recursively.
I just show you the csharp code:

```
        try {
            var arg = string.Format("{0} {1} /i/y/s/e/D", Path.GetFullPath("../www"), Path.GetFullPath("./EM/www"));
            var p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                FileName = @"xcopy",
                Arguments = arg,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };
            p.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            p.WaitForExit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("[FAIL] COPY: {0}", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
```

May it helps.

Comment: Thanks noncast. I have converted that code to Visual Basic but getting an error saying the first key must start with a '.'

Comment: Hi @nomcast I posted the code in a new answer as I was unable to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx). It's already implemented for you. But if you REALLY wanted to reinvent the wheel, I'd take a look into recursion if I were you.

Comment: Also, the xcopy suggestion is fine, but it seems almost like an abuse of Process.Start(). I'd reserve Process.Start() for tasks like restarting a process after it has been killed, or starting another application you've written or are using. It seems so similar to the abuse of system() in the C++ community.

Answer (score 0):

this is my first time to write vb.net code,

> Imports System.IO

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim arg = String.Format("{0} {1} /i/y/s/e/D", Path.GetFullPath("src"), Path.GetFullPath("dest"))
        Dim p = New Process()
        p.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo() With {
            .FileName = "xcopy",
            .Arguments = arg,
            .UseShellExecute = False,
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        }

        p.Start()
        Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
        p.WaitForExit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("[FAIL] COPY: {0}", ex.Message)
        Throw
    End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```